# Select data from another database in storedprocedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I try to select data from a table of another database in my storedprocedure and the name of the other database is given by parameter. I get an error message:

> 'Invalid object name [@DbName].dbo.Setup'.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUndeliverableOrders]
    @DbName sysname
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Sortfield nvarchar(50)

    SET @Sortfield = (SELECT COALESCE(Text, 'ToDoListeDatum') AS SortField FROM [@DbName].dbo.Setup WHERE label like 'ComboBoxSetupBatchReihenfolge')
END
GO
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL here

Answer (score 0):

Like @ThomasSchremser said:

```
DECLARE @sqlquery varchar(1000)
SET @sqlquery = '(SELECT COALESCE(Text, ''ToDoListeDatum'') AS SortField FROM ['+@DbName+'].dbo.Setup WHERE label like ''ComboBoxSetupBatchReihenfolge'')'
```

It is upto you to decide weither you what to populate a table/variable with the results.

Either use:

```
insert into @table(column) exec @sqlquery...
```

or

```
sp_executesql @sqlquery...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic query as below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUndeliverableOrders]
        @DbName sysname
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @Str varchar(max)

        CREATE TABLE #Result(Res VARCHAR(MAX))

        SET @Str = 'insert into #Result SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(Text, ''ToDoListeDatum'') AS SortField FROM ['+@DbName+'].dbo.Setup WHERE label like ''ComboBoxSetupBatchReihenfolge'''

        exec(@str)

        select Res from #Result
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified per your script：

```
    DECLARE @Str varchar(max)
    CREATE TABLE #Result(Res VARCHAR(MAX))

    SET @Str = ' SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(Text, ''ToDoListeDatum'') AS SortField FROM ['+@DbName+'].dbo.Setup WHERE label like ''ComboBoxSetupBatchReihenfolge'''
    insert into #Result
    EXEC(@Str)
```